# Extract xml comments for public members only

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

I'm using xml comments to document public as well as internal and private members of my components. I would like to package the generated documentation xml files with component assemblies in order to enable "rich" (e.g. with method, exceptions and parameter descriptions) Visual Studio Intellisense with the end product. The problem with it is that the C# compiler creates documentation entries for everything (including internal classes, methods, private fields of internal enums etc.) and there seems to be no switch to "only public members" mode.

Now I don't want to go over 50 files with XX methods in each and remove all comments for private and internal members. Even if I did that, I probably would not have much success with auto-gen'd resource files, because these strongly-typed resource classes are automatically commented and non-public.

My question is: is there some option/flag that I'm overlooking? If no, are there some tools that could help separate public members from the rest (before I start to code one)?

Answer (score 7):

SandCastle Help File Builder has an option to recreate the xml files containing only the configured access modes for methods, properties, etc...

The only "downside" is that you'll have to generate a documentation.

### EDIT

Since it's been a long time ago I forgot that I added a "component" to SHFB to generate the XML.

The good news is that this component is included in SHFB.

You have to add the "Intellisense Component" to the SHFB project. It will then generate the XML according to the configured SHFB project.

For more info: [Intellisense Component in SHFB](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/5d546511-6aec-455a-ba09-9daffb124c6d.htm)

Comment: Sorry but I can't find such option in SHFB

Comment: i see, but it will generate .chm file instead of .xml

Comment: Look in the output folder (have to keep it though) after SHFB has run and you will see the XML files.

Comment: Nope. There are just two files: .chm and .log

Comment: Wow cool! I'm already generating my documentation using SHFB so it's the best option for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool inside the [eazfuscator](http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx) that can remove non-public documentation. You can see an example [here](http://eazfuscator.blogspot.com/2010/10/xml-documentation-filter.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've given this some thought and I decided to change the way I go about solving this particular problem. Instead of finding type/member within the assembly trying to parse the XML documentation notation. I decided to simply build a string set (of XML documentation notation) for the public API that can then be used to tes wheter a member isn't public.

It's really simple. Send an assembly to the `XmlDocumentationStringSet` and it will build a string set of the public API and delete the elements that aren't public.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var el = XElement.Load("ConsoleApplication18.XML");

    // obviously, improve this if necessary (might not work like this if DLL isn't already loaded)
    // you can use file paths
    var assemblyName = el.Descendants("assembly").FirstOrDefault();
    var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName.Value);

    var stringSet = new XmlDocumentationStringSet(assembly);

    foreach (var member in el.Descendants("member").ToList()) // .ToList enables removing while traversing
    {
        var attr = member.Attribute("name");
        if (attr == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (!stringSet.Contains(attr.Value))
        {
            member.Remove();
        }
    }

    el.Save("ConsoleApplication18-public.XML");
}
```

And here's the class that builds the XML documentation names (it's a bit large but I thought I post the entire source here anyway):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    public class XmlDocumentationStringSet : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        private HashSet<string> stringSet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

        public XmlDocumentationStringSet(Assembly assembly)
        {
            AddRange(assembly.GetExportedTypes());
        }

        public bool Contains(string name)
        {
            return stringSet.Contains(name);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Heelloasdasdasd
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="types"></param>
        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<Type> types)
        {
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                Add(type);
            }
        }

        public void Add(Type type)
        {
            // Public API only
            if (!type.IsVisible)
            {
                return;
            }
            var members = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (var member in members)
            {
                Add(type, member);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        private void Add(Type type, MemberInfo member)
        {
            Type nestedType = null;

            sb.Length = 0;

            switch (member.MemberType)
            {
                case MemberTypes.Constructor:
                    sb.Append("M:");
                    AppendConstructor(sb, (ConstructorInfo)member);
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.Event:
                    sb.Append("E:");
                    AppendEvent(sb, (EventInfo)member);
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.Field:
                    sb.Append("F:");
                    AppendField(sb, (FieldInfo)member);
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.Method:
                    sb.Append("M:");
                    AppendMethod(sb, (MethodInfo)member);
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.NestedType:
                    nestedType = (Type)member;
                    if (IsVisible(nestedType))
                    {
                        sb.Append("T:");
                        AppendNestedType(sb, (Type)member);
                    }
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.Property:
                    sb.Append("P:");
                    AppendProperty(sb, (PropertyInfo)member);
                    break;
            }

            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                stringSet.Add(sb.ToString());
            }

            if (nestedType != null)
            {
                Add(nestedType);
            }
        }

        private bool IsVisible(Type nestedType)
        {
            return nestedType.IsVisible;
        }

        private void AppendProperty(StringBuilder sb, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            if (!IsVisible(propertyInfo))
            {
                sb.Length = 0;
                return;
            }
            AppendType(sb, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
            sb.Append('.').Append(propertyInfo.Name);
        }

        private bool IsVisible(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            var getter = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
            var setter = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod();
            return (getter != null && IsVisible(getter)) || (setter != null && IsVisible(setter));
        }

        private void AppendNestedType(StringBuilder sb, Type type)
        {
            AppendType(sb, type.DeclaringType);
        }

        private void AppendMethod(StringBuilder sb, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            if (!IsVisible(methodInfo) || (methodInfo.IsHideBySig && methodInfo.IsSpecialName))
            {
                sb.Length = 0;
                return;
            }
            AppendType(sb, methodInfo.DeclaringType);
            sb.Append('.').Append(methodInfo.Name);
            AppendParameters(sb, methodInfo.GetParameters());
        }

        private bool IsVisible(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return methodInfo.IsFamily || methodInfo.IsPublic;
        }

        private void AppendParameters(StringBuilder sb, ParameterInfo[] parameterInfo)
        {
            if (parameterInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            sb.Append('(');
            for (int i = 0; i < parameterInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(',');
                }
                var p = parameterInfo[i];
                AppendType(sb, p.ParameterType);
            }
            sb.Append(')');
        }

        private void AppendField(StringBuilder sb, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
        {
            if (!IsVisible(fieldInfo))
            {
                sb.Length = 0;
                return;
            }
            AppendType(sb, fieldInfo.DeclaringType);
            sb.Append('.').Append(fieldInfo.Name);
        }

        private bool IsVisible(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
        {
            return fieldInfo.IsFamily || fieldInfo.IsPublic;
        }

        private void AppendEvent(StringBuilder sb, EventInfo eventInfo)
        {
            if (!IsVisible(eventInfo))
            {
                sb.Length = 0;
                return;
            }
            AppendType(sb, eventInfo.DeclaringType);
            sb.Append('.').Append(eventInfo.Name);
        }

        private bool IsVisible(EventInfo eventInfo)
        {
            return true; // hu?
        }

        private void AppendConstructor(StringBuilder sb, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
        {
            if (!IsVisible(constructorInfo))
            {
                sb.Length = 0;
                return;
            }
            AppendType(sb, constructorInfo.DeclaringType);
            sb.Append('.').Append("#ctor");
            AppendParameters(sb, constructorInfo.GetParameters());
        }

        private bool IsVisible(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
        {
            return constructorInfo.IsFamily || constructorInfo.IsPublic;
        }

        private void AppendType(StringBuilder sb, Type type)
        {
            if (type.DeclaringType != null)
            {
                AppendType(sb, type.DeclaringType);
                sb.Append('.');
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            {
                sb.Append(type.Namespace);
                sb.Append('.');
            }
            sb.Append(type.Name);
            if (type.IsGenericType && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            {
                // Remove "`1" suffix from type name
                while (char.IsDigit(sb[sb.Length - 1]))
                    sb.Length--;
                sb.Length--;
                {
                    var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
                    sb.Append('{');
                    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            sb.Append(',');
                        }
                        AppendType(sb, args[i]);
                    }
                    sb.Append('}');
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return stringSet.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and I haven't figured out how to handle events yet, they are always visible in this example.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same requirement as what your code address. 7 years on, are you still using this, or have this evolved/changed into some even better way to strip out private/internal XML docs? Thanks.

Comment: @KristianWedberg hehe, glad it's been useful to you but I have moved away from .NET development in general. I think there are tools that can consume C# XML documentation and generate various results, maybe they have better support for custom needs. There's also Mono.Cecil which is a great library for reflection that doesn't require code loads, if you have complex assembly dependencies, Mono.Cecil is a great way to side step those issues.

Answer (score 2):

@John Leidegren

I've got the same requirement, and I've found the answer to the missing bit of your code. An Event has 2 methods, Add and Remove, and is considered public if either of them is public. So it would be something like:

```
private bool IsVisible(EventInfo eventInfo)
{
    return eventInfo.GetAddMethod(false) != null
        || eventInfo.GetRemoveMethod(false) != null;
}
```

although I can't think of any reason why one would be public and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using to generate the documentation?  I use Sandcastle and that gives you the option to select members to include by accessability.

In general it seems expected that the XML would contain all info that **could** be needed and its up to the processing tool to select from it what is needed.

Comment: I'm not talking about SandCastle, but rather about the xml files, since this is how you can enable function and parameter description in VS Intellisense tooltips.

Comment: If you use SandCastle and Sandcastle Help File builder, you can tell it to use only the public methods in the final document. Not exactly what you are looking for maybe?

Comment: I want to publish XML documentation for my class library so it will appear in IntelliSense

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. SHFB is slow as hell and since we have another documentation code-base we did not need it to generate the documentation for us.

I ended up using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) plus a separate namespace for internal classes. For example, all my internal classes would reside in `MyCompany.MyProduct.Internal`. Then I can use one simple command

```
xml ed -L -d "//member[contains(@name, 'MyCompany.MyProduct.Internal')]" MyProduct.xml
```

to cleanse the XML. This of course is not bullet-proof -- it does not cover internal members in public classes, and it does require some discipline to remember to put internal classes into internal. But this is the cleanest and least intrusive method which works for me. It is also a standalone EXE file easily checked into build server, no sweat.